# лидирующий 0 в числе

Tags: mysql

Делаю справочник организаций, БД MYSQL. Для хранения инн завел поле типа int. Однако бывают случаи когда инн начинается с нуля, и при сохранении, база данных сама убирает лидирующий 0. Например инн вида 0123456789 после сохранения превратиться в 123456789 . На текстовое поле переходить не хотелось бы, так как все таки это число. Есть какие нибудь варианты решения?

Comment: char для инн тип поля берите.

Comment: не хотел конечно в строку инн переводить но пришлось, на varchar переделал